# What Does $rootScope.$broadcast with Two Arguments Do

Tags: angularjs

I'm following along with this article: https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec#.rlvow9x66

I'm trying to implement their AuthInterceptor with a modification that handles status codes with multiple different types of errors. Here's my code:

```
angular.module('mobileDashboardApp')
    .factory('AuthInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, AuthEvents) {
        return {
            responseError: function (response) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast({
                    400: AuthEvents.notAuthorized,
                    401: if(response.header.messages === 'Your Session has timed out. Please login again.') {AuthEvents.sessionTimeout} else {AuthEvents.notAuthenticated},
                    500: AuthEvents.serverError,
                    503: AuthEvents.serviceError
                }[response.status], response);
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
    });
```

The problem is with the 401 if statement. Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
401: response.header.messages === 'Your Session has timed out. Please login again.' ? AuthEvents.sessionTimeout : AuthEvents.notAuthenticated,
```

Answer (score 0):

> What Does `$rootScope.$broadcast` with Two Arguments Do

The first argument is a text string with the name of the AngularJS event. The second and subsequent arguments are sent to listeners as arguments of the handler function.

### Broadcaster

```
$rootscope.$broadcast("eventName", { code: 404, name: "page not found"});
```

### Listener

```
$scope.$on('eventName', function eventHandler (e) { 
    console.log("got eventName");
    console.log(e.code);
    console.log(e.name);
});
```

For more information see [AngularJS $rootscope.scope API Reference -- $broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast)

## UPDATE

> in my example, what is the name of the event where the error code is 400 for example?

In your example, if you used the constants from [Techniques for authentication in AngularJS applications](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec#.knw72id2u)

### AUTH EVENTS constants

```
.constant('AuthEvents', {
  loginSuccess: 'auth-login-success',
  loginFailed: 'auth-login-failed',
  logoutSuccess: 'auth-logout-success',
  sessionTimeout: 'auth-session-timeout',
  notAuthenticated: 'auth-not-authenticated',
  notAuthorized: 'auth-not-authorized'
})
```

Your code evaluates to:

```
{
   400: AuthEvents.notAuthorized,
   401: (response.header.messages 
          === 'Your Session has timed out. Please login again.') ?
               AuthEvents.sessionTimeout : AuthEvents.notAuthenticated,
   500: AuthEvents.serverError,
   503: AuthEvents.serviceError
}[400] == 'auth-not-authorized'
```

Comment: in my example, what is the name of the event where the error code is 400 for example?

Comment: so can I use both $scope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized) and $scope.$on('auth-not-authorized')?

Comment: Yes, they are the same thing. If you use the first form, you need to inject `AuthEvents` in the function using it.